# Python: how to select indexes from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df
     0    1   2  3   4      
0   0.0 NaN NaN NaN NaN 
1   NaN 0.0 0.0 NaN 4.0 
2   NaN 2.0 0.0 NaN 5.0
3   NaN NaN NaN 0.0 NaN 
4   NaN 0.0 3.0 NaN 0.0
```

I would like to have a dataframe of all the couples of values different from `NaN`. The dataframe should be like the following

```
df
    i   j   val
0   0   0   0.0 
1   1   1   0.0
2   1   2   0.0
3   1   4   5.0
4   3   3   0.0
5   4   1   0.0
6   4   2   3.0
7   4   4   0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('i','j')).reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
    i  j  val
0   0  0  0.0
1   1  1  0.0
2   1  2  0.0
3   1  4  4.0
4   2  1  2.0
5   2  2  0.0
6   2  4  5.0
7   3  3  0.0
8   4  1  0.0
9   4  2  3.0
10  4  4  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
In [379]: df.stack().reset_index(name='val').rename(columns={'level_0':'i', 'level_1':'j'})
Out[379]: 
    i  j  val
0   0  0  0.0
1   1  1  0.0
2   1  2  0.0
3   1  4  4.0
4   2  1  2.0
5   2  2  0.0
6   2  4  5.0
7   3  3  0.0
8   4  1  0.0
9   4  2  3.0
10  4  4  0.0
```